# How to make the script works on IPv6 address

Tags: perl, sockets

I have a client script to receives TCP packet on IPv4 address.
Now, I need the script receives TCP packet on IPv6 address.
As I don't know much about perl-Socket, Can you help me modify it ?

```
use Socket;
use IO::Handle;
use constant MY_ECHO_PORT => 9067;
$ENV{'PATH'} = "$ENV{'PATH'}:./";

my ($bytes_out,$bytes_in) = (0,0);

my $dt;

my $port = shift || MY_ECHO_PORT;
my $protocol = getprotobyname('tcp');

local *SESSION;
local *SOCK;

$SIG{'INT'} = sub {
    close(SESSION) if SESSION;
    shutdown(SOCK,2) if SOCK;
    close(SOCK) if SOCK;
    print STDERR "Mlease agent stopped\n";
    exit 0;
};

socket(SOCK, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, $protocol) or
    die "socket() failed: $!";

setsockopt(SOCK,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,1) or
    die "Can't set SO_REUSEADDR: $!";

my $my_addr = sockaddr_in($port,INADDR_ANY);
bind(SOCK,$my_addr) or
    die "bind() failed: $!";

listen(SOCK,SOMAXCONN) or
    die "listen() failed: $!";

print "Mlease agent started on port $port...\n";
```

Comment: [IO::Socket::IP](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::IP) supports both IPv4 and IPv6

Comment: I used IO::Socket::IP, but it is still listen on IPv4. I think need to modify somethings

Answer (score 0):

**ipv6-agent.pl** based on [IO::Socket::IP](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::IP), executes received client command and sends the output back to the client

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Socket::IP -register;

use constant MY_ECHO_PORT => 9067;

my $port = shift || MY_ECHO_PORT;

my $sock = IO::Socket->new(
    Domain    => PF_INET6,
    LocalHost => "::1",
    Listen    => 1,
    LocalPort => $port,
    Proto     => "tcp",
    ReuseAddr => 1,
) or die "Cannot create socket - $@\n";

$SIG{'INT'} = sub {
    $sock->close() if $sock;
    print STDERR "Mlease agent stopped\n";
    exit 0;
};

while (1) {
    my $client = $sock->accept();

    # get information about a newly connected client
    my $client_address = $client->peerhost();
    my $client_port    = $client->peerport();
    print "connection from $client_address:$client_port\n";

    # read up to 1024 characters from the connected client
    my $data = "";
    $client->recv($data, 1024);
    print "received data: $data\n";
    chomp $data;

    my $res = qx/$data/;
    $client->send($res);

    # notify client that response has been sent
    shutdown($client, 1);
} ## end while (1)
```

run your script:
`perl ipv6-agent.pl`

run a client:

`nc ::1 9067
date
Wed Jun 28 08:27:20 CEST 2017`

Comment: Thank @palik. The agent has received data. In my case, the agent will execute a command after receiving from client. example : "received data: perl gendhcpv6 -a 1". Can you help me modify it in this script ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have just to execute the command sent by the client: `qx/$data/`